# Jvm heap being blown by multiple regression algorithm

Tags: java, algorithm, matrix, jvm, heap-memory

I am writing a Multiple Regression (similar to linear systems) algorithm for image processing. Considering that my images generate data matrices of `height*width, I can end up with really big structures.

The Multiple Regression algorithm is:

`x = inv(A'*A)*A'*b`

Where X is an array of coeficients, A is a matrix and B is a vector.

My implementation for this is:

```
public RealVector multipleRegression(double[][] coordinates, double[] data){
     RealMatrix m1 = new Array2DRowRealMatrix(coordinates);
     RealVector v1 = new ArrayRealVector(data);

     // A = (m1'*m1)
     RealMatrix A = m1.multiply(m1.transpose());

     // B = A^-1 -> Matrix inversion
     RealMatrix B = new Array2DRowRealMatrix();
     B = A.power(-1);

     // C = A*B -> inv(A'*A)*A
     RealMatrix C = new Array2DRowRealMatrix();
     C = A.multiply(B);

     // result = C*b -> result holds my coeficients
     RealVector result = new ArrayRealVector();
     DecompositionSolver solver = new LUDecomposition(C).getSolver();
     result = solver.solve(v1);

     return result;
 }
```

I have tried erasing everything but `RealMatrix A = m1.multiply(m1.transpose());` but that didn't work either. Given that, I tried doing the transpose operation before the multiply operation and the heap was blown as well.

I tried alocating 14GB of ram for my JVM but that wasn't enough.

Any suggestions?

Comment: It sounds like you'll need a solver that trades speed for memory use by writing the LU decomposition out to disk.  Your matrix must be big and dense enough where you can't have it all in memory.  Wavefront solvers have been used this way.

Comment: The heap is being blown at the first multiply function though. How would I override the implementation and write it on disk? I know I can do that for the solver, but can I do that for the multiply?

Comment: If your problem is that big you're truly lost.  Java heap is a generational model.  Which generation is "blown"?  Could it be perm space?  Profile the app and see where and when it's happening.  Use Visual VM if you have nothing else.

Comment: what are sizes of the matrices ?

Comment: Its an image Height*Width, considering that I was parsing a 354*255 image, it had 90270 rows of 9 columns each